# pundit rails - how to user .has_role? in another table other than role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

In using rails I run in to a situation where I have to use my own tables in authorizing the user rather that using the default role and user tables (i.e. user.has_role? on role table,).

how do I implement (authorize) using my own created tables in policy file for a certain model/class - as the roles and permissions are stored in another table: permissions table, where i have a user id, role id.

Thanks

Comment: What does your table structure look like and the associations?

Comment: Does this help you? http://culttt.com/2016/01/20/implementing-roles-and-permissions-in-ruby-on-rails/